# HTML Parsing using Jsoup, getting an exception

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I want to parse an HTML page in order to get the first.jpg link, and setting its link to a WebView, in order to view the image on the app. I use AsyncTask. It seems to work, but I encounter an exception on the Try block. On the LogCat it's just shown ERROR PARSING ERROR (as you can see, that's how I chosen in the Catch group). But no explanation on what causes the exception. The code is as follows:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        TextView prova = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.searchedName);
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("[url]http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/42997801")
                     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22")
                     .timeout(3000).get();
            String icon = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]").first().text();
            WebView summonerIcon = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            summonerIcon.loadUrl(icon);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "PARSING ERROR");
    }
    return null;

    }
```

Comment: e.printStackTrace(); in catch block will give you more details

Comment: apart from the answers posted you are also updating uo doInbackground which is wrong. Do it in onPostexecute

Comment: `But no explanation on what causes the exception` because you don't log any.

Comment: @Raghunandan I've applyed your changes, but it seems like jsoup can't parse the image URL, because I've tried to setText on a TextView with its URL but it goes blank... Did I something wrong while catching the url?

Comment: @user2834656 check your jsoup parsing. can you post which html tag you are parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String icon = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]").first().text();
```

will fetch the text in `<img>` tag.

Your code should read as below.

```
String icon = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]").first().attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Log.e("ERROR", "PARSING ERROR", e);
```

In order to log also the message `e` holds.

Answer (score 0):

`connect` expects a valid `URL`. Remove the `"[url]"` `String` in the method argument

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/42997801")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate `View`s inside a non-UI thread - in this case `AsyncTask`.
This might be causing problem:

```
TextView prova = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.searchedName);
...
WebView summonerIcon = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
summonerIcon.loadUrl(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

are you giving the permission of accessing internet in android maniefest file
  like this in your maniefest file